# How to package and deploy blackberry apps to device from Eclipse

Tags: deployment, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How do I package and distribute my apps from the Eclipse IDE?

My apps work within the simulators, but I have no idea how to deploy them to my blackberry device.

I moved the files to the Media card but I kept getting errors (i.e. invalid COD errors). Is there an appropriate way. It worked fine in the simulator!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your app uses any controlled APIs you will first need to get it signed by RIM. For more info on how to apply for code signing keys look [here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp). Once you have your keys installed you can sign your app through eclipse. If you're using Blackberry plugin 1.0 go to BlackBerry > Request Signatures, If your using plugin v1.1 go to Project > BlackBerry > Package All

If your app doesn't use any controlled APIs you can skip all of that and load the app with something like JavaLoader:
JavaLoader -u load [codfile]

Or you can fire up BB desktop manager and point it at your cod file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate - the JavaLoader approach totally worked! But what about distributing via OTA for my clients?

Comment: @Olaseni : The cod file has sibling .cod files zipped in it. Extract the main code files. Put your JAD file in the folder where you extracted that code file. Upload the folder on server and give your clients the url of JAD file. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Before installing your application into device you need to sign them. Try to install app with `BB desktop manager`, if this error continues, `clean and build your project from eclipse project explorer's context view`.

I also faced such problems coz my apps are targeted to 4.6 and 4.7 and their eJde's are problematic ones, So i switched deployment and debugging part in JDE rather than eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy tour Blackberry application this can help you to learn it step by step: [How to prepare and deploy a BlackBerry Java Application](http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/How%20to%20prepare%20and%20deploy%20a%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Application)