# How to change the switch application MenuItem text?

Tags: blackberry, configuration, menuitem

i need to change the text of the switch application MenuItem to "changer d'application" in French. 
I think it's not a deafult menu Item. I do searchs and I found a code returning the id and the ordinal of all the menuItems:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 try {
 MenuItem item = MenuItem.getPrefab(i);
 System.out.println("Item found: "+item.toString());
 System.out.println("id: "+item.getId()+" index: "+i);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("No item for "+i);
 }
 }
```

It didn't work for switch application! 
Have someone please any idea about how to change the text of switch application?
thanks

Comment: Unless I am very much mistaken the text for all of the OS menu items is in language resource files. The user selects the language they wish to use and menus etc are displayed in that language. I don't understand why you would want to override the users' choice here. Moste developers put a lot of work into internationalizing applications to provide this service to the user.

Comment: @Richard it's right thanks! I'm running my app with the BB simulator and it doesn't allow me to change language so I thought that I must set the language of the menu! (Sorry! I'm really new to BB dev). I'm trying now to install the app in a device and check this. By the Way is there any link explaining how to install the app in a bb device? Thank you very much :)

Comment: I think your question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222195/how-to-package-and-deploy-blackberry-apps-to-device-from-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add additional languages to the BlackBerry simulator.

See this BlackBerry support forum article:
[Add language support to the BlackBerry Simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Add-language-support-to-the-BlackBerry-Simulator/ta-p/445954)